# I am looking for the materializecss datetimepicker like bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: materialize

Hi I am trying to looking for materializecss datetimepicker, In official materializecss.com also I am not getting the datetimepicker only getting the timepicker and datepicker but i am not looking for that only I need like **bootstarpdatetimepicker** in the materializecss.

So kindly help me on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Ok , here is the direct code.

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

and here is the link for future reference. https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview